# How to troubleshoot connection issue

Tags: networking, vpn

I have the following problem, of which I can't make any sense.

I am sitting at home and I can't connect to my work PC. The VPN for the company network is running and working. I can connect to another machine, and from this machine I can connect to my work PC.

Thus, the VPN is working, the work PC is up and accepting connections. However, when I try to connect directly from my home to the work PC, even ping does not work.

Thus, I have the strange issue, that I can connect from machine A -> C -> B, yet not directly A -> B.

Where should I start digging, i.e. which log files are relevant for my problem?

---

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 on both my home PC and work PC, i.e. machines A and B. The intermediate machine runs CentOS 7.

The company VPN is provided by FortiGate and I am using the Unix client from Fortinet.

---

Updatee to add:

route -n on machine A, i.e. my home computer

```
x.y.z.0     ?.?.?.?     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 ppp0
```

route -n on machine B, my work PC

```
x.y.z.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
```

route -n on machine C, the other computer at work

```
x.y.z.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     101    0        0 eno1
```

What catches the eye, is the flag UG present at my work computer.

---

I found that rebooting the work PC does help.

With the current plague going on, working from home is still on-going.
However, since I work only a part of the week from home, I am frequently in the office, and occasionally reboot my work PC as some updates demand a reboot.

I strongly suspect, that if enough reboot-wanting updates have been made without actually rebooting the work PC - I sometimes run lengthy simulations on my work PC, so shuting it down at the end of the day is something I do seldomly.

So, my current theory that sometimes my work PC is in an "updated-yet-not-rebooted" state, and that this blocks SSH-logins via VPN, while SSH-logins from within the company's network, i.e. from the other machine, are still possible.

Does this make any sense?

*Thank you, to everybody who read and thought about my question, even if did not comment or interacted otherwise.
Remote IT problems, i.e. those that one has to describe instead of demonstrate to an actual onlooker, are quite hard. First, to properly describe; and second, to convey enough information for anybody to be able to come up with an answer.*

Comment: Are you able to share the output of `ip a` and `route -n` on your local computer, and the IP addresses of computers B and C?

Comment: Thank you for adding the route information, but it is not very useful without being able to identify specific subnets, IPs, etc., plus there should be at least 2 important routes on machine A (LAN and VPN).